# Batch: Selecting all files with a certain extension from a directory

Tags: batch-file, command-line, youtube-api

Instead of executing my pythong command for one file at a time (in this example the 01.mp4 file) I would like to loop through all .mp4 files in the directory.

```
python C:\Users\Name\File.py --file="C:/Users/Name/Desktop/01.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /R C:/Users/Name/Desktop %%f in (*.mp4) do python C:\Users\Name\File.py --file="%%f"
pause
```

That should work in this case. This executes your command (`python C:\Users\Name\File.py --file="<filename>"`) on each of the .mp4 files in the C:/Users/Name/Desktop directory

Comment: I end up with the command written in the command line and nothing else

Comment: have you used `@echo off`? And are you executing this from cmd or in a batch file?

Comment: What does the python command do? You should also put @echo off above your code if you don't want to see the commands it executes, and a pause after it if you don't want the screen to immediately close